# How can I fix this corrupted rpmdb?

Tags: linux, rpm, corruption, berkeley-db, corrupt-data

My rpmdb is corrupted, and the usual procedure for fixing it doesn't seem to work.

This is the error:

```
cris@PolariSuse [~]$ rpm -qa > /dev/null
error: rpmdbNextIterator: skipping h#   64697
Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, key ID 3dbdc284: BAD
Header SHA1 digest: BAD (Expected bf167126ecaa67d16fee74af17096529278aad8d != cd4a91ad1f0d65d360cce5dacffea553e358b550)
```

If I try to fix it I get this:

```
cris@PolariSuse [~]$ sudo rpmdb --rebuilddb
[sudo] password for root:
error: cannot add record originally at 64697
warning: failed to rebuild database: original database remains in place
```

I even tried *db_dump* against the Packages file and subsequent *db_load*: it apparently works but the newly produced Packages file has the same error.

However, I see that after rpm gets the error while listing packages, it is nonetheless able to continue listing the subsequent packages, so ideally I would like to rebuild the Packages file skipping the corrupted record.
Unfortunately I have not found any utility capable of doing it.

Does anybody know another way of fixing this corrupted db?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the header and reinstall.

See the rpm man page for how to erase given a header # (the 64697 in the message you posted).

You may need --nosignature --nodigest to disable the checks that are failing

Comment: Jeff, thank you for your reply! 
However, I'd be very grateful if you could elaborate on that. I looked at the man page, but I cannot see anything related to a header #, especially not under the options for the erase operation.
I also tried the --hdrid and --pkgid options but both replied with the same error: "error: malformed pkgid: 64697".

Comment: Grrrr ... rpmdb --rebuilddb has been changed to stop on an error.

Comment: One way to remove the record is to save the output of db_dump on Packages and edit out the record with a text editor. The db_dump format is the key followed on next line by the value (I.e. an rpm header). The key is the hdrid in hex. Use a pattern match to find the key, then delete that key and value. Then proceed to feed the file to db_load.

Comment: Jeff, again thank you for your hints. I exported my db with db_dump. What I do not understand is if I have to look for the key id (which is 3dbdc284) or the hexadecimal representation of the header (64697). And if the latter: do I have to take the 64697 as a number and convert it to hex? Or do I have to convert the 6-4-6-9-7 characters and use their hex representation? If you don't mind, I extrapolated all the keys from the exported db, they are available [here](https://pastebin.com/UuWR8L2d). Would you be so kind to take a look at them and tell me which is the one I have to delete?

Comment: Convert 64697 the number, not the as ii chars) from decimal to 8 digits of hex: that is the primary key in the db_dump output.

Comment: OK, so obviously 64697 is hex FCB9 that is 4 digits, not 8. But I see that all keys end with '0100', so I looked for 'FCB90100'. There is no key like that unfortunately :(  Even looking for 'FCB9' alone does not return anything. At least, not among the keys.

Comment: Mmm, I thought that maybe, because of the endianness I had to look for 'B9FC' instead, and actually there is this key 'b9fc0000' that also has the added weirdness of ending in '0000' instead of '0100' (but it is not the only one, although they are very rare). Do you think this could really be the key I'm looking for?

Comment: The keys will be much shorter than the headers, and will be unique, and on a single line. Otherwise post 20-30 lines from the beginning of the db_dump output and I'll try to point out what to look for.

Comment: Jeff, I see the structure of the export file, thanks to you. The point is that, among the keys, there isn't the key that rpm complains about. But please see my last comment from May 15th. 
Anyway, you can find the first 20 lines of my db_dump [here](https://pastebin.com/cwqTKd1Y).

Comment: Thanks for the output. See the first record with key 0: the value is the largest hdrNum. The 2nd record has a key !=1 which indicates that the keys have been made persistent through --rebuildid, but perhaps not the error message. Deleting that damaged record is still viable: just the record will have to be located by its value content.

Comment: So look at --rebuilddb -v -v output. Look for a unique string in that output. Convert that string to hex, and locate the hex value in the db_dump output. The next 2 lines are likely to be the damaged header.

Comment: One good candidate for locating the damaged record value is the header SHA1 digest.

Comment: Jeff, this is mostly above my head, but I'll try to follow through. Thank you for all your help! I will let you know.

Comment: All I was really trying to say is find the SHA1 in the db_dump output. That is likelely the bad header.